# How to clone div with html controls without their content using jquery & refresh dropdown for IE?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery

I am using **jquery .clone()** function to clone a **div** which is having **6 controls (dropdowns, textboxes etc)** .I have a functionality where there are 2 dropdowns **DDL A** & **DDL B** . Now changing the DDL A item populates content in DDL B. This function works fine in **Chrome** , **Firefox** , **Ipad** but doesn't work in **IE** .

> The scenario is like I clone the div of 6 controls to add a new row for
>       data entry, & when I select item from DDL A , it shows the corresponding item
>       in DDLB. But when  again I select other item from DDL A, the options of DDL B
>       don't get refreshed . It is strange that in Firebug of IE the DDL B shows 
>       proper options, but the view doesn't.

Is it that IE doesn't refreshes dropdown before repopulation or it doesn't understands jquery
.clone() function ? Can anyone help me get a proper solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with IE is that it does not clears dropdown when we script

**$("#ddlB").empty();**

The rest of browsers work fine with this snippet.

So we need to use

**$("#ddlB")[0].options.length = 1;**

These clears the old dropdown state & data in IE. I am now successful to create a functionality where I clone divs with different html controls . Following is the snippet

```
$(function () {
    $('.addRow').click(function () {
         var clickNumrow = $(this).data('clickNumrow');
         if (!clickNumrow) clickNumrow = 1;
         $("#original").clone(true).insertBefore('.addnewRow').attr('id', 'original_' + clickNumrow);
         $("#original_" + clickNumrow + " select#materialid")[0].options.length = 1;
         $(this).data('clickNumrow', ++clickNumrow);
     });  
});
```

I finally could refresh the dropdown on selection change of dropdown item

```
$(function () {
     $('select#categoryid').change(function () {
         var url = "/Material/FillMatByCatId";
         var ddlsource = this;
         var prt = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
         var ddltarget = '#' + prt + ' select#materialid';
         if ($(this).val() != '') {

            $.getJSON(url, { CatId: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
                $(ddltarget)[0].options.length = 1;
                $(ddltarget).empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {

                $(ddltarget).append("<option value='" + optionData.Value + "'>" + optionData.Text + "</option>");
                });
            });
         }
     });
});
```